# Image Skeletonization using Medial Axis Transform

Tags: c#, c++, image-processing, image-manipulation

My requirement is something like this:

Lets take there is a `Bitmap` with a big letter 'A'.
The `Bitmap` is two colors (Either Black or White).

I need to skeletonize the big 'A'. (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton)
Using "Medial Axis Transforming" algorithm.

I tried my best in googling but i ended up being lost in finding a C#, C++ or at least pseudo code implementation of this algorithm.

I would like if someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two articles are the ones where the Medial Axis Transform was first proposed, so I think that you can find the algorithm to implement there. Do not expect a C++/C# implementation though.

- [A transformation for extracting new descriptors of shape](http://pageperso.lif.univ-mrs.fr/~edouard.thiel/rech/1967-blum.pdf)
- [Shape description using weighted symmetric axis features](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=GatewayURL&_method=citationSearch&_uoikey=B6V14-48MPGXX-33&_origin=SDEMFRHTML&_version=1&md5=e53a049b310993550fa50e64960bd29e)

For the first one I was able to find a URL to a pdf. For the second one you will have to have access to ScienceDirect to download.

Another approach that you can use to extract the skeleton of a shape is by the Image Foresting Transform (IFT). It consists in representing the binary image as a graph. I made an implementation of the skeletonization by IFT in Matlab using the following article:

- [Multiscale skeletons by image foresting transform and its applications to neuromorphometry](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~afalcao/mo815-grafos/a16.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This page http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~algorith/files/thinning.shtml has some sources you may wish to review.